# How to set the min/max attribute on input type=date

Tags: html, date, max, min, html-input

I'm having some problems to set a minimum and a maximum YEAR with HTML5 date input.

Here is my code:

```
<input required="required"  min="1900-01-01" max="2099-09-13" type="date" class="form-control" id="inputDataNascimento">
```

It doesn't work at all.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Notes: I'm using Google Chrome and Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Comment: a min or max would need to be a number, it is a string currently.

Comment: even for the "date" type? i've seen some examples around using this format...

Comment: looks like I am wrong, the date format is part of spec sorry. [html 5 form input](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp)  Though as other have commented , your mileage may vary.

Comment: Which browser are you using for your tests? I have heard there is very little support for min and max attributes for date input type. Try with Chrome.
It is not min or max attributes that limit the day and month. It seems min and max are not working at all.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers like Safari and Internet Explorer do not support this functionality; this may be your problem. Write validation via JavaScript.

The list of browsers that support this feature can be seen at:

http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-33/firefox-27/opera-19/safari-7.0/ie-11.html

Comment: I'm using Chrome :/ . Date is working. 'min' and 'max' are not. :(

Comment: Are you using Jquery? There are some nice widgets there some nice date functions. [query ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Answer (score 3):

min and max attributes for date input type have very little browser support. You can use jQuery validation as a workaround.

```
<input id="dateInput" required="required"  min="1900-01-01" max="2099-09-13" type="date" class="form-control">
<script>
    $("#dateInput").validate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML datepicker component now works in most browsers and the minimum and maximum control attributes are fully implemented. The correct format is `yyyy-mm-dd`, as described at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" min="2020-01-20" max="2021-01-28">
```

A simple example adapted from w3school:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show a Date Control</h1>

  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" min="2020-01-20" max="2021-01-28">

<p><strong>Note:</strong> type="date" is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 11 (or earlier).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

As supplementary information, from the HTML5 specification documentation.

In session [4.10.5.1.7 Date state (type=date)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#date-state-(type=date)), we read:

> The min attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid
> date string. The max attribute, if specified, must have a value that
> is a valid date string.

And in the other session, [4.10.1.8 Date, time, and number formats](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-date-string), we find:

> ...is intended to be computer-readable and consistent irrespective of
> the user's locale. Dates, for instance, are always written in the
> format "YYYY-MM-DD", as in "2003-02-01".

Comment: Sadly, the minimum and maximum controls *still* don't work for Safari on iOS.

Comment: "Fully implemented" is in the eye of the beholder.  In Chrome, at least, the min and max apply to the date picker associated with the input, but not with changes typed into the input box.  (As of Version 93)