# How do I set the min attribute for <input type="date"> via h:inputText?

Tags: html, jsf, html-input, passthrough-attributes

I have the following HTML calendar:

```
<h:inputText t:type="date" value="#{data.dueDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</h:inputText>
```

How can I add the `min` attribute for this?

`t` refers to `xmlns:t="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input type date you can use `min` and `max` attributes. You can set the `min` attribute the same way you used passthrough to set the `type="date"` attribute. So, for example:

```
<h:inputText t:type="date" t:min="2016-12-31" value="#{data.dueDate}">
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</h:inputText>
```

See also:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-date-string
- [min/max attribute with type = date on HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232638/min-max-attribute-with-type-date-on-html5)
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime